# Returning multiple values in the same field using INNER JOIN MYSQL

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I'm having trouble right at the very end I think. What I'm needing is to return countries that have a language of either Greek or Hebrew.

Here is my current code:

```
SELECT country.Name, countrylanguage.Language
FROM country
INNER JOIN countrylanguage
ON country.Code = countrylanguage.Countrycode
WHERE countrylanguage.Language IN 'Greek' OR 'Hebrew';
```

Comment: Use: `IN ('Greek' , 'Hebrew')`

Answer (score 1):

```
IN 'Greek' OR 'Hebrew'
```

is incorrect syntax, you should use either of the following:

```
WHERE countrylanguage.Language IN ('Greek', 'Hebrew')
```

or

```
WHERE countrylanguage.Language = 'Greek' OR countrylanguage.Language = 'Hebrew'
```

I'm not sure the performance implications but the first one seems 'cleaner'.